# Should I reference ASP.NET MVC as NuGet package?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I've an ASP.NET MVC application which I've upgraded from 2.0 to 3.0 in the past and now I want to upgrade it to 4.0.

I've tried to create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project in VS2012 and it seems that ASP.NET MVC itself is now a NuGet package.

Should I reference it in form NuGet package like in the new project templates or just reference like 2.0 and pre 3.0 tool update (separate assemblies)?

My servers have ASP.NET MVC 4 installed so having MVC dll's in /Bin seems to be a waste of space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NuGet` nowadays is the way to go. If you are still dealing with assemblies manually, I fear you're doing it wrong.

You definitely should install it through a `NuGet` package. This will allow you no headaches when new updates appear. NuGet knows how to manage package dependencies correctly, that is, it'll also update all other packages you have installed in your project to make them compatible with the latest `ASP.NET MVC`. Things are really EVOLVING for the better in this specific case! :)

Comment: So I will no longer need to install ASP.NET MVC packages on the servers?

Comment: Yes... no need to install it on the server... the assemblies will be copied automatically to your bin folder on deploy.

Comment: Side note: I'm using NuGet for everything else except ASP.NET MVC itself, I just don't know that the official package exists :)

Comment: Yes... the ASP.NET team migrated almost everything to NuGet. NuGet is really powerful when dealing with package dependencies.

Comment: By the way, how ASP.NET MVC assemblies are resolved now on the server? They are here `C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\` and not installed in the GAC. How they are found?

Comment: They are automatically deployed to your app `bin` folder on deploy. If you select for example in the References of your project the DLL `System.Web.Mvc` and press `F4` to see the properties you'll see that it has `Copy Local = True`. This means that the DLL will be placed in the `bin` folder.

Comment: No, I have Copy Local = False and I don't have Assemblies in /Bin. It works when I install ASP.NET MVC on server as standalone install.

Comment: So you should change Copy Local to `True`. This is automatically set to `True` when installing ASP.NET MVC from NuGet. I'm using VS 2012 RTM and ASP.NET MVC 4.